# Iterate through list in a list and show in table

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a list in a list and it looks like:

```
List<List<Integer>> coverage
```

In my controller i'm giving it to the model.
In my template I want to iterate through the lists of integers in the list and show this in 1 table.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td class="table-colspan" colspan="1" >1</td>
        <td class="table-colspan" colspan="1" >2</td>
        <td class="table-colspan" colspan="1" >3</td>
        <td class="table-colspan" colspan="1" >4</td>
        <td class="table-colspan" colspan="1" >Total</td>
        <td class="table-colspan" colspan="1" >6</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="title-tr" th:each="list : ${coverage}">
        <tr class="title-tr" th:each="r, iterationStatus : ${list}">
            <tr th:text="${r}"></tr>
            <td th:text="${r}" ></td>
            <td th:text="${r}"></td>
            <td th:text="${r}"></td>
            <td th:text="${r}"></td>
            <td th:text="${r}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I first iterate through the List to get each `List<Integer>`
After this I iterate through the `List<Integer>` itself to view the integers.
But each integer from the `List<Integer>` gets its own row. So the first integer in `List<Integer>` is showing up 6 times.

How can I fix this?

I hope my situation is clear enough, otherwise I will give additional information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts the thymeleaf code is in my question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to include the `tr` tag inside other `tr` tag. If you want to iterate through columns, change it to:

```
<tr class="title-tr" th:each="list : ${coverage}">
   <td th:each="r, iterationStatus : ${list}" th:text="${r}">
   </td>
</tr>
```

P.S. Because it is not quite clear for me what you want to achieve, just another hint: if you want to iterate through `tr`'s, use `th:block` wrapper instead of including `tr` into the another `tr`:

```
   <th:block th:each="list : ${coverage}"> 
       <tr th:each="r : ${list}"> ... </tr>
   </th:block>
```